# `open` command not passing `--args`

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to start a pyinstaller executable with the `open` command on my Mac, but I need to pass an argument identifying the port to open.

When I run `./app 5000`, the executable opens correctly.

When I run `open app --args 5000`, the executable doesn't recognize the argument and an error is thrown (`IndexError: list index out of range`).

In my executable, I'm trying to access the argument like this: `app_config = {"port": sys.argv[1]}`.

How can I use the `open` command and pass an argument to my executable?

Answer (score 0):

`--args` is used with option `-a`.

So you need to install your app, and then

```
open -a app --args 5000
```